# github actions not receiving secrets

Tags: github-actions

I've seen other SO answers but none of them seem to work. I guess I'm just trying to do something pretty simple with Github Actions. Just make a access_key available to my github action, without putting it in my github repo. So I see we can create `action secrets` that **should** be passed to the github action. I also understand we cant just log secret keys for security, so I would expect `***` instead when trying to log. For the life of me I can't figure out why the secrets are not `***` but they are empty. And even when Im using them in my scripts, they don't appear to have any value to them. Here is my workflow thats relevant

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
env:
  AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_PRODUCTION_BUCKET_NAME }}
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
  AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      CI: true
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        publish_dir: ./build
    - name: Test Env
      run: |
        echo 'The GitHub Action Secret will be masked:  '
        echo ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        echo 'Testing secret if its masked: '
        printenv
```

When I run this, I see that `GITHUB_TOKEN` is indeed `***`, which makes sense. But all the secrets that I've added to my repository settings > secrets > action secrets, they are just blank, not `***` and if i try to use them via `${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY }}` its also blank.

My repo is public, I am pushing to master as well. I have admin rights to my repo.

Comment: also i am doing `printenv` here because i have tried `${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY }}` and i wanted to just see what the env looked like

Answer (score 40):

In my case I hadn't referenced the environment containing the secrets from my script. Eventually found this in the documentation but it's incredibly frustrating that it just returns blank secrets instead of raising some kind of error message.

```
jobs:
  myjobname:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: myenvironment  # THIS WAS MISSING
    steps:
      # The steps in the action
```

Documentation link: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment

Comment: Thank you!!

I can't believe secrets are this hard to use. Took me 2 hours. Do better GitHub

Comment: Saved me from being stuck an entire day! Oh God!

Comment: Additionally, another potential cause is that "secrets are not passed to the runner when a workflow is triggered from a forked repository". This issue arises when attempting to push changes to an organization's repository from a forked version.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was trying to use secrets in an included workflow file (from the same repository). That will only work if you use `secrets: inherit`. For example:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/.build-application.yml
    # The following is required to use secrets in .build-application.yml:
    secrets: inherit
```

See documentation at https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#passing-inputs-and-secrets-to-a-reusable-workflow

Comment: This was exactly what was happening on my end. Thank you, just saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 5):

Ok looks like theres different kinds of secrets. I was adding `Action Secrets` which makes sense to me. I want secrets for Actions. Theres another section called `Environment Secrets` which when I put it in that, it worked. Kinda confusing.

Answer (score 1):

One big problem I can see is that you are trying to access the secrets outside jobs. From the official documents [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow), it is done at the level of the steps through encryption.